# Specify release artifacts for in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a python package, and I want to release the package versions occasionally. I added the following in the CI configuration, and it does create releases successfully.

```yaml
release_version:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - artifacts: false
      job: registry_upload
  release:
    description: release of version ${VERSION_NUMBER} of my_package
    ref: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    tag_name: v${VERSION_NUMBER}
  script:
    - echo release of ${VERSION_NUMBER}
    stage: release
    variables:
        VERSION_NUMBER: 0.0.1
```

(`registry_upload` is the name of the job with `twine`)

However, the release page only shows zip, tar, tar.bz2 and tar.gz of the repository, and has no link to download the corresponding wheel files (created in previous jobs and exposed as artifacts), or not even a link to the package registry.

My question is how to specify file paths or artifacts of previous jobs (wheel files, html documentation by Sphinx, etc.) so that those are available directly from the release page, without needing the access and/or need to go to the pipeline/package registry and download from there.

Comment: Previously asked at https://forum.gitlab.com/t/specify-release-artifacts/75546?u=anirban.ray